# PL/SQL nested if statement

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, nested

I'm creating a function that ensures all outdated employee ids are updated to be have a total of 4 numbers. For example, if a employee's id was 11, it would be concatenated with two 0's: 0011.
I keep getting an error:

```
Error(19,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when 
        expecting one of the following: if
```

It is flagging at the first nested if:

```
create or replace function ID_RENEWAL(OLD_ID IN VARCHAR2)
return VARCHAR2
is UPDATED_ID VARCHAR2(4);
begin
if (length(OLD_ID) < 4) THEN
   UPDATED_ID := '0'||OLD_ID;
    if (length(OLD_ID) < 4) THEN
     UPDATED_ID := '0'||OLD_ID;
      if (length(OLD_ID) = 4) THEN
        return (UPDATED_ID);
      end if;
   end if;
else
  UPDATED_ID := SUBSTR(OLD_ID, 1, 4);
return (UPDATED_ID);
end;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The bigger issue is If the employee's ID is used as a primary key in your database this may break all kinds of things from a data normalization point of view.  Instead add an attribute to your employee table indicating if the employee is outdated or not (whatever that means) and leave their ID alone.  If you change the ID it will no longer match with any reporting, etc that already used that ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to end each `IF` statement with `END IF`. The following would be correct:

```
IF (length(OLD_ID) < 4) THEN
  UPDATED_ID := '0'||OLD_ID;

  IF (length(OLD_ID) < 4) THEN
    UPDATED_ID := '0'||OLD_ID;

    IF (length(OLD_ID) = 4) THEN
      return (UPDATED_ID);
    END IF;
  END IF;
ELSE
  UPDATED_ID := SUBSTR(OLD_ID, 1, 4);
END IF;
```

The concrete error message stems from the fact that you did not put an `END IF;` after your `ELSE`, which is why the function-terminating `END;` was parsed as an incomplete `END IF;`

Comment: That worked! I didn't realize to include the end ifs

Answer (score 0):

This is a more simplified form:

```
create or replace function ID_RENEWAL(OLD_ID IN VARCHAR2)
return VARCHAR2
is 
UPDATED_ID VARCHAR2(4);
begin
    SELECT LPAD(SUBSTR(OLD_ID,1,4),4,'0') INTO UPDATED_ID FROM DUAL;
return (UPDATED_ID);
end;
```